# Get Last Apache/PHP Error

Tags: regex, bash

I would like a command/script that when run returns the last error message in apache and php logs. It should read the date/time from the last line of each log and only output lines that match that date/time.

Comment: Why script ? You can use PHP's error_get_last function to get the last occurred error.http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: I need errors for php and apache printed on bash command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use cat, watch, grep with regex and pipe (that's the vertical line that looks like this `->  | <-`)